# "==" vs "equal(Object obj)"

Tags: java

Can I understand the differences between `==` and `object.equal(Object obj)` in the following way? :

That's `object.equal(Object obj)` returns `true` if **values** of two objects are identical. While `==` returns `true` if both **type** and **value** of two objects are identical.

Comment: Note that `==` can never change meaning, but `equals()` can.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`==` returns true if the references are exactly the same.

`equals(Object)` returns true when the method is written to return true.  This can be the same object, an equivalent object or what ever the developer felt like writing.

The default implementation is written as

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    return (this == obj);
}
```

so you can see it does the same thing.

Comment: I am only asking about the default implementation of equals(Object obj)

Comment: I would have read the source code, its not very long and would have answered your question immediately. ;)

Comment: If you don't know how to find the source easily, you can usually look it up in you IDE.

Answer (score 2):

The default behavior of `java.lang.Object.equals` and `==` is to return true if both references a and b point to the same object; false otherwise.

If you wish to compare values, you have to override equals.  That's what `String` and some other types have done.  You don't get it for free; you have to override the method from `java.lang.Object`.

Best to read Joshua Bloch's "Effective Java" [chapter 3](http://java.sun.com/developer/Books/effectivejava/Chapter3.pdf) to see how to do it properly.

Comment: Then, what is the difference between these two?

Comment: `==` always means referring to the same object. What `equals` means depends on the type of object whose `equals` method you call.

Comment: Because some Objects, like String and Number, have already overridden equals.  My statement is the one that's true for objects that you write if you don't override equals.

Answer (score 0):

`object.equals(Object obj)` returns `true` when the objects are identical according to the object's attributes depending on the type of the object and if that method bas been implemented.

`==` returns `true` when the instance of the object is the same.

Comment: Can you explain what does 'identical' means? Same class type and same value?

Comment: It depends if the class that you call the `equals` from actually implements that method. In a `String` that would compare all the characters one by one and if they are the same return true.

Comment: you can consider like equals method is for string comparison and == used to check for object identification (object location)!!

Answer (score 0):

The implementation of Object.equals is:

```
public class Object {
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        return (this == obj);
    }
}
```

This returns `true` only when `obj` is exactly the same object as `this`. Like Peter Lawrey said in his answer, the definition of `equals` for any other class depends entirely on how it is coded. There isn't even a requirement that the two objects be the same class, or even hierarchically related classes.

Note that defining `equals` without also defining `hashcode` is generally considered bad practice. There's a requirement that two objects that are `equal` must return the same hash code.